# Sending password to server

Tags: objective-c, ios, security

I am asking myself. What is the best way to send personal information from your iOS device to the server.

At this moment I encrypt the password in the app ( sha1 salt password pepper ) then I send post data using from iOS to the server.

What is the best way to protect the user and secure for any MITM attacks. Is my way secure enough?

**UPDATE:**

I added the SSL certificate. To make sure the user only has to login once I store a key generated when the user registered. I fetch them when the user logins for the first time. In oombination with the username and user id. Is this a good way? Only jailbroken users can read it and have risk.

Comment: @CodesInChaos that is a joke right?

Comment: @Woot4Moo Why? It's standard practice and certainly better than any homebrew scheme you might construct. Just be sure to use appropriate certificate validation(e.g. hardcoding the fingerpring).

Comment: @CodesInChaos you said send in plain text, I wasn't commenting on the use of TLS (which as far as I know is correct)

Comment: @Woot4Moo What I mean is that you don't need to do anything beyond the encryption TLS already provides. No client side hashing or similar fanciness.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hashing the password on the client side will help prevent the password itself from being detected in eavesdropping, but it really doesn't provide any security on its own, as the credential then becomes the hashed version of the password, not the original password itself. An eavesdropper could just grab the hashed version, and then send the hash themselves.

By far the easiest solution is to simply use SSL/TLS. Since you mentioned 'post', that means you're probably using HTTP. Instead, you could just connect via HTTPS and post the data, exactly the same as you're doing already. Long as the certificate is checked for validity (I believe the iOS framework already does such by default), then the connection should be largely secured.

That should be *good enough* for most situations. There are some more complicated and involved techniques you can use to harden further, but SSL/TLS does a massive amount on its own.

Comment: err, client side hashing (where the attacker lives), is not secure in the least.

Comment: Sending the password plain text over the web isn't too. I will edit it to client-side hashing and server-side hashing

Comment: @Woot4Moo If you're trying to design a system to be secure against an attacker that's controlling the client device, then not even TLS will help you, beyond a little security through obscurity (they could still extract/modify whatever data they wanted before being encrypted, while in memory). Client side hashing provides a very minor amount of security (not for the account, though!), and is far inferior to using TLS to secure the connection. SSL/TLS is an obvious-right choice. Going beyond that, you'd need a very good understanding of security, otherwise you're unlikely to be improving things.

Comment: @Kitsune It sounds like you have a fundamental misunderstanding of security.  I say that because you say hash instead of encrypt yet you explicitly call out TLS.  I would recommend you heed your own advice and not offer incomplete solutions to security related problems.  However, I could be wrong and you could be some security guru that did their PhD thesis on preventing MITM attacks.

Comment: @Woot4Moo Where did I say to hash instead of encrypt? I pointed out why client side hashing does nothing against eavesdroppers' ability to hijack accounts, and that SSL/TLS is the brain-dead simple way to secure communications, and is *good enough* for most scenarios.